Do I need concrete footings for a wooden retaining wall?
I'm planning to build a short (16") wooden retaining wall in my back yard. The general idea is to sink 4x4s into the ground every 32" and then attach 2x8s behind them so the back fill helps hold everything together. I'll use 3/4" gravel back fill and leave a small gap between the 2x8s and also between the 2x8s and the ground on the lower side to allow for drainage. I'll be using pressure treated lumber rated for ground contact for everything.
I was told to sink posts twice as deep as the height of the retaining wall, so my plan is to sink 4' posts 32" deep (plus a 4" gravel base for drainage). Do I still need to cement the post in, or will the post depth be sufficient without? Or: if I opt for concrete footings, can I use shorter posts (say, 16" depth)? Which would be cheaper?
This is in the Pacific Northwest, so it will face plenty of rain and cold, in case that factors in.

Just a comment that if I was building a very short retaining wall I would just use the stackable landscape blocks that step back with each row. You will never have to worry about concrete blocks rotting out in your lifetime.

Do not use concrete. Just bury the 4x4s the 32 inches and tamp the fill back around them.  Footing are to support weight on them vertically. That is not your issue here.  Concrete around a wood post will trap water and make it rot faster.
